# Separate month from year in Python data frame

Tags: python

I have a 1000 x 6 dimension data frame and one of the columns' header is "Date" where the date is presented in the format "JAN2014", "JUN2002" etc...
I would like to split this column in two separate columns: "Year" and "Month" so JAN will be in "Month" column, 2014 will be in "Year" column etc.. 
Could anyone please tell me how to do this in Python?

Comment: Could you give an example of your data?

Comment: I have 6 columns: TYPE, ID, COUNTRY, CITY, DATE, AMOUNT. The "DATE"  column has the format  "JUN2002". Thererfore I would like to replace this column with two separate columns lets say "MONTH" and "YEAR" where the year ( 2002) will be placed under "YEAR" column and month (JAN) will be placed under  "MONTH" column.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the str accessor and indexing:

```
df['Month'] = df['Date'].str[:3]
df['Year'] = df['Date'].str[3:]
```

Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date':['JAN2014','JUN2002']})
df['Month'] = df['Date'].str[:3]
df['Year'] = df['Date'].str[3:]

print(df)
```

Output:

```
      Date Month  Year
0  JAN2014   JAN  2014
1  JUN2002   JUN  2002
```

Comment: That helps! And what if I dont want to keep the "JAN2014" format in my output? Therefore I want to replace "Date" columns with "Month" and "Year" columns. Thanks

Comment: `df = df.drop('Date', axis=1)` will remove that column from the dataframe.